# is there any way to fix solr index

Tags: solr

I am running a program that crawls the web and saves data into a solr index. for mysterious reasons, the solr server crashed. And now I end up with a corrupted index that has no segment files and hence risking losing all my data collected for 5 days....

The error message reads as below when you try to search on this index. the index folder definitely has data, as it has 182 files and 2GB in size.

I have tried to use CheckIndex but get the same error about no segment files...

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [chase]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$6(CoreContainer.java:586)
    at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedRunnable.run(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:176)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:229)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [chase]
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:935)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$5(CoreContainer.java:558)
    at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedCallable.call(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:197)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening new searcher
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:977)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:830)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:920)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening new searcher
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.openNewSearcher(SolrCore.java:2069)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getSearcher(SolrCore.java:2189)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initSearcher(SolrCore.java:1071)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:949)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.index.IndexNotFoundException: no segments* file found in LockValidatingDirectoryWrapper(NRTCachingDirectory(MMapDirectory@/home/zqz/Work/chase/aws/data/solr/chase/data/index lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@51b2fc7e; maxCacheMB=48.0 maxMergeSizeMB=4.0)): files: [_fh2.fdt, _fh2.fdx, _fh2.fnm, _fh2.nvd, _fh2.nvm, _fh2.si, _fh2_Lucene50_0.doc, _fh2_Lucene50_0.pos, _fh2_Lucene50_0.tim, _fh2_Lucene50_0.tip, write.lock]
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:925)
    at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.<init>(SolrIndexWriter.java:118)
    at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.create(SolrIndexWriter.java:93)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DefaultSolrCoreState.createMainIndexWriter(DefaultSolrCoreState.java:248)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DefaultSolrCoreState.getIndexWriter(DefaultSolrCoreState.java:122)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.openNewSearcher(SolrCore.java:2030)
    ... 12 more
2017-06-20 14:38:52.428 INFO  (qtp475266352-16) [   ] o.a.s.c.TransientSolrCoreCacheDefault Allocating transient cache for 2147483647 transient cores
2017-06-20 14:38:52.894 INFO  (qtp475266352-13) [   ] o.a.s.s.HttpSolrCall [admin] webapp=null path=/admin/cores params={indexInfo=false&wt=json&_=1497969532681} status=0 QTime=11
2017-06-20 14:38:52.962 INFO  (qtp475266352-20) [   ] o.a.s.s.HttpSolrCall [admin] webapp=null path=/admin/info/system params={wt=json&_=1497969532684} status=0 QTime=76
```

Comment: first thing: run CheckIndex on your index

Comment: tried this, but it also generates the same error about no segment files found

Answer (score 0):

The error you mentioned is caused by the missing file :
segments* e.g. segments_3 ...
in the index files :
files: [_fh2.fdt, _fh2.fdx, _fh2.fnm, _fh2.nvd, _fh2.nvm, _fh2.si, _fh2_Lucene50_0.doc, _fh2_Lucene50_0.pos, _fh2_Lucene50_0.tim, _fh2_Lucene50_0.tip, write.lock]

That file specifies the last commit point and the last generation of segments to take into account and apparently it is missing.
Check if that file is there and is readable.

If it is not ( because for example the index writer was not closed properly due to the mulfuction, do not despair.

Chances are there that the transaction log contains still the documents you indexed, so you could just replay it and get the documents back ( clean the index dir, make solr starting and it should take care).
Solr allows also a backup functionality, so for the future you may want to configure it.

Comment: thank you. no the file are not there. The program was running on AWS amazon cloud and i had no idea why the server crashed. And when I went to gather data, that's just what was left... unfortunately I cannot re-index the files, as in this case I was crawling twitter stream and there is no way to 're-do' the live stream.

Comment: Do you have the Transaction log ( tlog) enabled ?
It is useful in case of disaster recovery.

Comment: I am not sure, how do i know?

Comment: do you have a tlog directory in your data directory ?